# PHPMailer giving rtf file .txt extension

Tags: yii, phpmailer

First time using PHPMailer within Yii and i've got the files to attach fine in email form using .doc, .rtf and .txt. I then tried to add the optional name to the file rather than the uploaded name and my rtf file was sent as a .txt file. Not sure why? Wondered if anyone could point me int he right direction.

```
$mail = new YiiMailer();
//$mail->clearLayout();//if layout is already set in config
$mail->setFrom('email@example.com', 'Me!');
$mail->setTo(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail']);
$mail->setSubject('Mail subject');
$mail->setBody('Simple message');
$mail->AddAttachment($dest . '/' . $file->tmp_name . '.' .$file->extension, $file->name);
```

Thanks in advance

Jonnny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that if I pass all the arguments to the AddAttachment() it sends the RTF as a .doc file.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($dest . '/' . $file->tmp_name . '.' .$file->extension, $file->name, 'base64', $file->mime_type);
```

Jonnny